# React without ES6 modules

Tags: reactjs, playframework, ecmascript-6, render

Im currently playing with Scala, Play framework and React sample code and ran into an issue while trying to convert the following code to load in the browser without using ES6 module system. This means I cannot use `export default`.

How do I go about rewriting the following in ES6 so I can load it on client side without `export default` ? Do I have to break this down to a class and a function that returns a `render` ?

```
export default function form({
  fields: defaultFds = [],
  validate: defaultVal = () => ({}),
} = {}) {
  return (WrappedClass) => class Form extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
      fields: defaultFds,
      validate: defaultVal,
    }

    static childContextTypes = {
      form: PropTypes.object,
      fields: PropTypes.object,
    }

    static propTypes = {
      fields: PropTypes.array,
      validate: PropTypes.func,
      value: PropTypes.object,
      onChange: PropTypes.func,
      onValidate: PropTypes.func,
    }

    state = {
      touched: {},
      errors: {},
      valid: undefined,
    }

    render() {
      const { value, onChange, onValidate, validate, fields, ...otherProps } = this.props;
      return <WrappedClass {...otherProps} {...this.generatedProps()} />;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to rewrite the entire thing here... because if you can't use ES6 you have more to worry about than `export default` -- all of the functions defined with `() =>` need to be rewritten, and you likely won't be able to use JSX.

Have you read the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html) on the subject?

Comment: Yeah i realized that :(. Ended up figuring out how to integrate webpack